# Date Value from Lookup Field displays in default View, but not in custom View

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-view, custom-list, json

I have a series of Lists in SharePoint Online.  In one List (Plans with Related Findings), I have several Lookup fields to another List (Plans).

I'm able to get the Plan Name into a custom view using json, but every time I try to display the date Lookup Value from that List (field name is "Plan_x0020_Name_x003a_Plan_x00200" but displayed as "Plan Name:Plan Start Date"), it's blank.  I've tried a lot of iterations, but here's an example of what I have right now:

**Format Columns for this Field:**

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "style": {
    "display": "flex",
    "flex-direction": "column",
    "align-items": "flex-start",
    "padding": "11px 0",
    "min-height": "0"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "div",
      "txtContent": "[@currentField.lookupValue]",
      "style": {
        "padding-bottom": "1px"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**Here's json for the Format View:**

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/row-formatting.schema.json",
  "hideSelection": true,
  "hideColumnHeader": true,
  "rowFormatter": {
    "elmType": "div",
    "attributes": {
      "class": "sp-row-card ms-font-m"
    },
    "style": {
      "box-sizing": "border-box",
      "border-width": "0.5px",
      "border-radius": "10px",
      "border-style": "solid",
      "padding": "0px",
      "margin": "3px 0px 3px 0px"
    },
    "children": [
      {
        "elmType": "div",
        "style": {
          "display": "table"
        },
        "children": [
          {
            "elmType": "div",
            "style": {
              "display": "table-row"
            },
            "children": [
              {
                "elmType": "div",
                "attributes": {
                  "class": "ms-fontColor-white ms-bgColor-themePrimary"
                },
                "style": {
                  "display": "table-cell",
                  "padding": "10px",
                  "text-align": "right"
                },
                "txtContent": "Plan Start Date:  "
              },
              {
                "elmType": "div",
                "attributes": {
                  "class": "ms-fontColor-white ms-bgColor-themePrimary"
                },
                "style": {
                  "display": "table-cell",
                  "padding": "10px",
                  "text-align": "right"
                },
                "txtContent": "[$Plan_x0020_Name_x003a_Plan_x00200.lookupValue]"
              },
              {
                "elmType": "div",
                "style": {
                  "display": "table-cell",
                  "padding": "10px"
                },
                "txtContent": "=join([$Findings_x0020_Name.lookupValue], '\n')"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "elmType": "div",
            "style": {
              "display": "table-row"
            },
            "children": [
              {
                "elmType": "div",
                "attributes": {
                  "class": "ms-fontColor-white ms-bgColor-themePrimary"
                },
                "style": {
                  "display": "table-cell",
                  "padding": "10px",
                  "text-align": "right"
                },
                "txtContent": "Plan Due Date:  "
              },
              {
                "elmType": "div",
                "attributes": {
                  "class": "ms-fontColor-white ms-bgColor-themePrimary"
                },
                "style": {
                  "display": "table-cell",
                  "padding": "10px",
                  "text-align": "right"
                },
                "txtContent": "[$Plan_x0020_Name_x003a_Plan_x0020.lookupValue]"
              },
              {
                "elmType": "div",
                "style": {
                  "display": "table-cell",
                  "padding": "10px"
                },
                "txtContent": "=join([$Shift3], '\n')"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**NOTE** that the `"[$Findings_x0020_Name.lookupValue]"` is being displayed fine.

Does anyone have something else I can try to get a dat value displayed in s a custom view?  I know the data exists, as I see it in the default list view.

Comment: Try using like this without `lookupValue`: `"txtContent": "[$Plan_x0020_Name_x003a_Plan_x0020]"`. Make sure you are using correct **[internal name](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)** of your extended lookup date column. Let me know if it works for you.